# How to make the first column fixed in a row grid and the others horizontally scrollable

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an object as follows

```
{
  A:[
    {subject:'U','teacher:'1'},
    {subject:'V','teacher:'2'},
    {subject:'W','teacher:'3'},
    {subject:'X','teacher:'4'},
    {subject:'Y','teacher:'5'}
  ],
  B:[
    {subject:'U','teacher:'1'},
    {subject:'V','teacher:'2'},
    {subject:'W','teacher:'3'},
    {subject:'X','teacher:'4'},
    {subject:'Y','teacher:'5'}
  ],
  C:[
    {subject:'U','teacher:'1'},
    {subject:'V','teacher:'2'},
    {subject:'W','teacher:'3'},
    {subject:'X','teacher:'4'},
    {subject:'Y','teacher:'5'},
  ]
}
```

Now I want to display each object key-value pair in a row and.
So now in a row I have multiple columns of which the first column is the objects key i.e(A, B, C) and then the other column would have the values of keys printed i.e all objects in the array of repective keys. I want the main object key i.e (A,B,C) to be fixed in the column and the rest to be horizontally scrollable. I tried the following

```
<v-card>
 <v-card-text class="card-body">
  <v-row class="flex-nowrap" v-for="(value,key) in data" :key="key">
    <v-col md="4">{{key}}</v-col> // this would print A,B,C. I want this col to be fixed
    <v-col md="2" v-for="(arrObj,i) in value" :key="i">
      <span>{{arrObj}}</span>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
 </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

And

```
.card-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So this makes the whole card scrollable. But I want to first col to be fixed and the rest cols of the row to be scrollable. How can I achieve this? Or Is there any other way to achieve this. Also I do not want to display this data in table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on your problem.

```html
<v-card-text>
  <v-row>

    <v-col md="4" class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="key">{{ key }}</div>
    </v-col>

    <v-col md="8" class="d-flex flex-column" style="overflow-x: auto">
      <!-- Set the width to ridiculous amount to simulate overflowing div for scrolling -->
      <div style="width: 2000px;" v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="key">
        <span v-for="(arrObj, i) in value" :key="i">{{ arrObj }}</span>
      </div>
    </v-col>

  </v-row>
</v-card-text>
```

[image]

So basically, I have two iteration for the `data` variable for each column. (I know, it looks dirty). Then, I've set a fixed width for the divs on the second column so it will not be wrapped on the column's width causing the column to overflow.

[Here's a sample demo at codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-field-gn4td?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:128-712)